# Return object after comparing-and-swapping if NOT equal?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, compare-and-swap

I have a class with an atomic variable:

```
class{
    public:
        std::atomic<int> _a;
};
```

I want to "retrieve" `_a`, only when its not a particular value. If it matches the invalid value, we should return false, otherwise we should make`_a` zero and return true. I thought of something like this:

```
bool retrieveIfValid(int& result){
    int valueAShouldNotBeQualTo = 9999999;
    bool success = _a.compare_exchange_weak();    // Need to exchange when _a NOT equal to valueAShouldNotBeQualTo
    result = _a.load();
    return success;
}
```

However, the problem is I am trying to use compare-exchange not for equal, but rather not-equal.

Does anybody have a smart way of doing this without using locks?

Comment: Have you tried a mutex?  CAS (compare and set) is a common hardware instruction that does the operation atomically.  I don't think (but don't know) that ...UAS? (uncompare and set) ... or whatever ... exists in any hardware implementation.  Probably you could do it with some really careful memory barriers in C++ more efficiently than a pure mutex-based guard, but that gets tricky.

Comment: I am avoiding locking

Comment: Is one of the threads subject to being suspended?  Or are you under the impression that lock-based synchronization is slower than lock-free synchronization?

Comment: 1) load current value. 2) if invalid return false, else 3) CAS `_a` to zero, if success return true, else 4) go to 1.

Comment: Could you add to your question that '_a' should be modified after the call and not just 'result'? At least this is what I understood from the word "retrieve"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, where `result` always carries the current value of `_a`

```
bool retrieveIfValid(int& result)
{
    int valueAShouldNotBeQualTo = 9999999;

    result = _a.load();

    do {

        if (result == valueAShouldNotBeQualTo)
            return false;

    } while (!_a.compare_exchange_weak(result, 0));

    result = 0; // _a was changed to 0
    return true;
}
```